# Получение полного пути выделенного объекта в проводнике

Tags: windows, delphi

Всем привет. Каким образом можно получить полный путь к файлу или папке?? Кстати, если может помочь, то у меня в проводнике есть созданная кнопка вручную. По идее можно получить путь откуда запустил и добавить туда название папки. Но как именно это сделать?? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Функция **ExtractFilePath** извлекает из **FullFileName** подстроку пути.
Это часть полного имени файла включая конечный  перед именем файла. 
 + еще несколько функций:

- `ChangeFileExt`  - Изменяет расширение имени файла
- `ExtractFileDir` - Извлекает из полного имени файла название папки
- `ExtractFileDrive` - Извлекает из полного имени файла название диска
- `ExtractFileExt` - Извлекает из полного имени файла его расширение
- `ExtractFileName` -  Извлекает из полного имени файла краткое имя файла
- `ProcessPath` - Разделяет строку диск/путь/имя файла на ее составляющие части

Пример:

```
ShowMessage('Путь = '+ExtractFilePath   (Application.ExeName));

Путь = C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\
```

Comment: Врядли. В шелле все пути в виде `ITEMIDLIST`, а в строки их превращают только для взаимодействия с внешним миром.